# How can I replace-by-fee an unconfirmed transaction sent from my Ledger Nano?

Tags: transactions, unconfirmed-transactions, ledger-hardware-wallet, replace-by-fee

Would anyone here please be able to tell me how to do RBF using the Ledger Nano—I can see the transaction was RBF and has been stuck for about 24 hours now. The TX is 5c119ce4b0bce440c16b2ad48e720c22422454118bf15ece0602904349d0b568 and it still has not been accepted.

I have been looking at accelerating it and also RBF, I have been unable to find anything for RBF in line with Ledger Live. I would really appreciate any help and if you could look at the transaction ID for me. I do not understand it unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ledger Wallet doesn't support RBF but you can do Child Pays For Parent:

Make a transaction to your address `3M6EhQL3QUQHAFkSPH3vLc3VDCrJKP3iMv` with amount  `0.011`, set a fee rate, preview the transaction and check and confirm the transaction **only if** one of the inputs is `0.01187067` BTC.

If this doesn't work, [download Electrum](https://support.ledger.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005161925-How-to-use-Electrum-with-your-Nano-S) and CPFP from [there](https://bitcoinelectrum.com/how-to-do-a-manual-child-pays-for-parent-transaction/).

But honestly, the fee rate of your transaction is not terribly low. I would wait another 24 hours.

Comment: It came through, just had to wait even longer- cheers pal :)

Comment: Glad that it's solved now!